# Can we use ASP.NET MVC3 along with classic ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have ASP.NET application in which some pages are designed using MVC3 architecture and some with classic ASP.NET (with view state ..etc) I want to merge these two projects in One. Or Is there any predefined **Controller** in MVC3 that can deal with this specific requirement?

Can we make some URL patterns to be dealt with Classic ASP.NET and some with MVC3 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can "classic" ASP.NET pages and Microsoft MVC coexist in the same web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132687/can-classic-asp-net-pages-and-microsoft-mvc-coexist-in-the-same-web-application)

Answer (score 1):

Why YES you can!

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

He also has another post using a [NuGet package](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingANuGetPackageIn7EasyStepsPlusUsingNuGetToIntegrateASPNETMVC3IntoExistingWebFormsApplications.aspx) to integrate the two...