# Gradualy migrate ASP.NET 4.0 to MVC3 keeping separated projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, migration

We are now starting to implement a new software product inside what we call a platform that aggregates several types of applications.

We will be doing it in MVC3, but I'm trying to avoid keeping the ASP.NET and MVC together in the same project, so that we can enforce some guidelines and dependencies (that are incorrect in the previous project setup).

My idea is that working apart from the production product, clean start the technical project and develop while we address big design decisions (localization, authentication, SOC, Unit Testing, etc) will be the best opinion in the long term (designing a legacy free product)

---

**What is your opinion:**

1.Merge from day 1 (1 project)

2.Keep them separated (2 project) and invest time merging them

3.Develop MVC apart till main decisions are made (deploying to another IIS), then merging them together in a single project

---

I have read this questions:

[Classic ASP and MVC side-by-side, different projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782572/classic-asp-and-mvc-side-by-side-different-projects)

[How to migrate existing asp.net application to asp.net MVC pattern format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532227/how-to-migrate-existing-asp-net-application-to-asp-net-mvc-pattern-format)

I'm tempted to try a merge on deploy (in cruise control) keeping both project separated, but immediately face global.asax merging between the 2 projects!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say merge from day 1. It will make your life easier later. The problem with keeping them seperate is that they will diverge more and more and you may begin duplicating code. It will make it much easier to migrate code if they live in the same project.

The first question you reference is about **Classic ASP** not ASP.NET

See:

[Can "classic" ASP.NET pages and Microsoft MVC coexist in the same web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132687/can-classic-asp-net-pages-and-microsoft-mvc-coexist-in-the-same-web-application)

[Can MVC 3 and WebForms co-exist on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257854/can-mvc-3-and-webforms-co-exist-on-a-website)

http://www.chadmyers.com/Blog/archive/2007/11/30/asp.net-webforms-and-mvc-in-the-same-project.aspx